# How do I remove a specific index from pd pivot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

My pivot like this:

```
                     01-12      02-12     03-12
Hospital                   
h1                    12         12         42
h2                    15         55         13
h3                    14         42         22
h4                     3          3          3
h5                    15         34         22
```

and I would like to remove index h4 from this pivot

```
                     01-12      02-12     03-12
Hospital                   
h1                    12         12         42
h2                    15         55         13
h3                    14         42         22
h5                    15         34         22
```

`df = df.drop(df.iloc[df.index == 'h4', :])` return an error. How can I do this?

Comment: `df.loc[df.index!='h4']` or `df.drop(['hr4'])`?

Comment: Great. This is what I ment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.drop('h4')
```

And you can drop several rows with a list:

```
df.drop(['h4', 'h5'])
```